# Kyokasuigetsu's Kanzen Saimin (Complete Hypnosis) Escape Method

Tags: anime, bleach

During Ichimaru gin's betrayal toward Aizen in Bleach, he mentions that the only way to escape Kyokasuigetsu's power, Kanzen Saimin or Complete Hypnosis, is to touch the tip of the blade before it is released. Now what confuses me is whether you would need to touch the tip of the blade every time before it is released, or just once and Kyokasuigetsu would never be able to affect you?

Comment: One HeroesCon attendee suggests that "Shikai" is the answer to this. Can anyone verify? Huh?

Comment: Shikai is the name of the initial release, like Rukia's katana turning into a white sword called Sode-no-shirayuki. It doesn't answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

After re-watching Bleach, seeing how Ichimaru Gin keep holding Aizen's sword before he stabbed him, I think one would need to constantly holding the blade to escape Kanzen Saimin, since Gin didn't let go of the blade before stabbing Aizen. Adding to this hypothesis is during Hirako Shinji vs Aizen battle, Aizen asked him since when did he is under the impression that Aizen is not using Kyoka Suigetsu's power, which means that when Aizen decided to release his shikai, you won't even notice it. Should Gin let go of Kyoka Suigetsu's blade, Aizen will release it immediately **without** Gin noticing it.

And watching early episodes of Bleach where Unohana found about Aizen's fake body who turns out to be Kyoka Suigetsu itself, touching the blade after it's release won't nullify Kanzen Saimin. Therefore to escape Kanzen Saimin, one must touch and keep holding onto the blade before the release.

What a troll Aizen is. Ckckck.